# Why when I submit the value of the text box in AJAX to a PHP script does it fail and give me a JSON parse error?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is my script in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        var email = $('.email').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register_email.php",
            data: { "email": email },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It reads the value of the textbox that was on the page that was submitted into the variable `email`. I can alert that out and it will show it.

However, if I put, something like `asdou` in the box and hit submit, I get this error:

`parsererror SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "asdou"`

My HTML is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Syllable - iPhone Speed Reader</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="images/app-icon.png" alt="App icon">

            <h1>Syllable</h1>
            <p>Speed reading app for iPhone. Devour all your Instapaper and Pocket articles, and learn to read much faster in the process.</p>

            <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email me when it's live">
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
            </form>

            <a href="http://twitter.com/syllableapp"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with what I put in? The page is visible at http://syllableapp.com/test if that's helpful. I just can't figure out what's wrong with my JSON.

Comment: On your input field, do you have the id or the class set to 'email'?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the HTML.

Comment: My guess is your php isn't returning json.