# Why when I send data with POST in AJAX to PHP does it say the variable is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        var email = $('.email').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register_email.php",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "email": email }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The `email` variable is definitely set, I can `alert` it out.

However, when I get to the PHP, this is my script:

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "...", "...", "...");

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        echo "Could not connect to database.";
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $emerd = json_decode($_POST["email"]);

        $db->query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES (' " . $emerd . "')");

        echo $emerd;
    }
?>
```

It always alerts "null" back to me. Why won't it understand what I'm POSTing?

Comment: You don't need `JSON.stringify({ "email": email }),`.. just `{'email': email}` should be good enough.

Comment: You don't need the `json_decode()` on the php side either

Comment: See the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105211/jquery-ajax-post-to-php) for some ways to handle it.

Comment: what's the output of `json_decode($_POST)`? It seems to me you're trying to access the email post variable which doesn't exist as you decided to post json not urlencoded

Comment: @JoeMinichino I get this, oddly enough: http://i.imgur.com/RSUkjhZ.png I don't understand why, http://syllableapp.com/test/register_email.php is accessible.

Comment: @Vega This guy said I needed to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279472/why-when-i-submit-the-value-of-the-text-box-in-ajax-to-a-php-script-does-it-fail

Comment: @DougSmith Just keep in mind that there's more than one way to do a post. If you really need to post JSON, then you need to properly stringify it, and deal with it as JSON on the server. But if you've got simple data like just a single email address, you can post it as traditional form-encoded key-value pairs. Watch your raw request (browser dev tools or Fiddler) to see what your post value really is. Something like `email=abc%40example.com` is probably perfect for your scenario, so you can leave JSON out of the request completely, then reading the post in PHP is much easier.

Comment: @DougSmith The default post for URL-encoded would be called like: `jQuery.ajax({type:"post",url:"someurl",data:{email:"abc@example.com"}}` - note that the `data` is not stringified and you're not giving it a JSON content type. This will produce the post value like I have in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your email field in a form like this

```
<form id="myform"><input type="text" name="email"></form>
```

then use jQuery to serialize it

```
$('#myform").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();//this keeps the form submission from refreshing the page
   var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: '',
      data: data,  //assign the data like this
      type: "post",
      success: function (response){

      },
      ....other params 
   })
})
```

this is the best way to do this IMHO and I think it is the recommended way for this kind of thing. No need to encode to JSON and then decode the JSON on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a `json` string back to your JavaScript. You should do:

```
echo json_encode(array(
   "email" => $emerd
));
```

Besides that, you don't need to:

- Use `json_decode` on your `$_POST["email"]` in php
- Set the `contentType` option or `JSON.stringify` your data object in your `$.ajax` request

Comment: Inspect your XHR activity using FireBug \ Chrome Developer Tool and see what is the response.

Comment: @JeffNoel No, he doesn't need to use `JSON.parse`, jQuery is already giving him a parsed object.

Comment: I get "register_email.phpFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" from the console.

Comment: How does that make any sense? I can access it directly.

Comment: Attach your updated JS and PHP code. Make sure there is no error in your PHP script.

Comment: PHP: https://gist.github.com/christianselig/6252852 JS: https://gist.github.com/christianselig/6252860

Answer (score 0):

Don't encode it to array, neither the quotes around "email" are needed.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register_email.php",
        data: { email: email, contact:$('#contact').val() }, //no problem even if you have more than one variables.
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

On server side,

```
$emerd = $_POST["email"];
```

Comment: This guy said I needed the quotes and stringify though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279472/why-when-i-submit-the-value-of-the-text-box-in-ajax-to-a-php-script-does-it-fail